# Observer pattern in microservice

Tags: java, design-patterns, microservices, observer-pattern

Currently I am reading the book called: Head First Pattern Design, there is one design pattern called: Observer pattern, like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

While I was reading that design pattern, I was feeling that currently we often use queuing system to publish and subscribe tasks between each microservices. Got a feeling that the Observer pattern is not quite often be used currently.  **Please correct me if I am not right, if could provide some example about using observer pattern in mircoservice will be excellent!**

Comment: Video streaming services, Stock exchange systems, Repository systems etc... will have Observer pattern underlying to them

Comment: @Tej, could you explain more in detail?

Comment: For example in terms of video streaming services. A single subject i.e the video will be observed by different observers like analytics service that captures the time spent on video and UI observer that will update the visual components of the page

Comment: One of the best reads I had that helped me be a bit more clear on this topic is https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-observer-design-pattern-is-kind-of-like-a-podcast-cdee5ef9f074

Comment: @Tej, thanks, in brief, do you mean serval services work as publishers and one or two object models work as subscribers, the service updates will be reflected on those models?

Comment: Sorry I meant one video is the Subject and it is being observed by analytics and UI observers

Answer (score 0):

I think an Atom Feed is what you are looking for on a microservice level

https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AtomFeeds.html

We use this pattern to distribute DomainEvents in our Domain. The other services subscribe on this interface and get notified as soon as the providing service publishes a DomainEvent. This works quite well and there is no polling or stuff like that included.

We code in .net, so on the first search this seems like promising java implementation:

https://github.com/rometools/rome

or an how to for c#

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-atom-feed

Comment: @SimonsOn thanks! could you provide some sample code? that help me more to understand..

Comment: @Chwa we code in .net, so I do not know a java implementation. But this seems like fitting library https://github.com/rometools/rome

Comment: @SimonsOn that' great, actually my .net knowledge is better than java

Comment: @Chwa try this then ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-atom-feed